# Private Cocoapod with Swift

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods

Trying to do a small private pod for internal consumption (will be part of a private git repo), but running into issues with classes not visible to workspace that uses the pod.  Here is my podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name = "DBKit"
s.version = "1.0.0"
s.summary = "Core Data library"
s.platform = :ios, '8.0'
s.requires_arc = true
s.author = { "John Doe" => "support@myemail.com" }
s.homepage      = "mywebpage.com"
s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
s.source   = { :git => "https://git.mycomany.com/scm/lss/dbkit-ios.git" }
s.framework = "UIKit"
s.source_files = 'DBKit/**/*.swift'
end
```

I have an test project that I am trying to use the pod in.  Here is that Podfile:

```
platform :ios, 8.0

use_frameworks!

def devPods
pod 'DBKit', :path => '~/Dev/Libraries/DBKit'
end

target 'SwiftCoreData' do
    devPods
end
```

The errors I am seeing are "Use of unresolved identifier 'CDManager'"

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Errors]

I have used the same classes within that project and had no issues.  I know the classes and methods in the pod are fine, problem is that the project that includes the pods doesn't see the methods.  I DO get intellisense on the imports statement for DBKit.

Both projects (the pod and the project using the pod) use Swift exclusively.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the declaration of that `CDManager` class look like?

Comment: @JoshCaswell - it was internal.  Once I fixed that and the methods that I needed exposed, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Like a dork, I hadn't bothered to make the class public.  Doing that and making the relevant methods public solved the problem.